# File Upload in angular

Tags: javascript, html

Name of the file is not getting displayed in label after selecting the file.

```
  <div class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input"
          aria-describedby="txtFileUpload" accept=".csv">
      <label class="custom-file-label" id="txtFileUpload" >Choose file</label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the above code works file see below

```html
 <div class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input"
          aria-describedby="txtFileUpload" accept=".csv">
      <label class="custom-file-label" id="txtFileUpload" >Choose file</label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom `class="custom-file-input"` is a bootstrap class and you need to provide necessary script which processes the file and displays the name:

```js
  $(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
  var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
  $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
  </div>
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_forms_custom.asp